# How to find the nearest number before or after a particular text in python

Tags: python, regex

**Sample Text:**

```
1. There are 500 employees in our organisation.

2. Abbott employed approximately 103,000 people as of December 31, 2018

3. We currently employ approximately 1,750 employees

4. As of December 31, 2018, we had approximately 25,300 full-time employees.
```

Now I want to find the nearest number before or after the word 'employe'.

```
c = re.search(r'(\w+\s+){0,3}employe(\w+\s+){0,3}', text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(c.group(0))
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1. 500
2. 103,000
3. 1,750
4. 25,300
```

With the above code I tried to find nearest words and then find the number in it.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: so you expect 2 result items `500` and `1.750` ?

Comment: yes, i'll edit it in the question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, some expression similar to:

```
(?:\bemploye\D{0,20})([0-9][0-9,]*)[^.,]|([0-9][0-9,]*)[^.,](?:\D{0,20}employe)
```

might also work to some extent with some modifications.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E3uMc4/1)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"(?i)(?:\bemploye\D{0,20})([0-9][0-9,]*)[^.,]|([0-9][0-9,]*)[^.,](?:\D{0,20}employe)"
string = """
1. There are 500 employees in our organisation.
2. Abbott employed approximately 103,000 people as of December 31, 2018
3. We currently employ approximately 1,750 employees
4. As of December 31, 2018, we had approximately 25,300 full-time employees.
5. As of December 31, 2018, we had approximately 30 full-time employees.
6. As of December 31, 2018, we had approximately 3 full-time employees.
"""
print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
[('', '500'), ('103,000', ''), ('', '1,750'), ('', '25,300'), ('', '30'), ('', '3')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lx9OP0/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/lx9OP0/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of lookaround assertions for the digits to make sure there are no non whitespace chars `\S` at either side.

To match before or after `employe` you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

The values will be either in capturing group 1 or in capturing group 2.

```
(?:(?<!\S)(\d+(?:,\d+)?)(?!\S)\D*\bemploye|\bemploye\D*(?<!\S)(\d+(?:,\d+)?)(?!\S))
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?<!\S)` Assert what on the left is non a non whitespace char
  - `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits and optionally a comma and 1+ digits.
  - `(?!\S)` Assert what on the right is not a non whitespace char
  - `\D*\bemploye` Match 0+ non digits, wordboundary and employe
  - `|` Or
  - `\bemploye\D*` Wordboundary, employe and 0+ non digits
  - `(?<!\S)(\d+(?:,\d+)?)(?!\S)` Capture **group 2**, same pattern as before
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TitmBc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dcjTX7)